# How can I access system mail in /var/mail/ via thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, system, mail

I've got cron jobs sending mail to my user at `/var/mail`. I know how to access that at the command line with the mail command. But, while a big command line fan, I do not like reading mail (even system mail) that way.

My mail client of choice is Thunderbird. Can I read /var/mail messages in Thunderbird? How?

I'm running Ubuntu 9.04 and Thunderbird 2.0.0.24 (though I'm soon to upgraded to 10.04).

Comment: Similar/duplicate question is [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301988/using-movemail-with-thunderbird-on-ubuntu/1103958#1103958)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In **Ubuntu 10.04**, with Thunderbird 3, the option is accomplished by:

1. Select `Edit`,   `Account Settings`

   [image]
2. Choose `Account Actions`,   `Add other account`

   [image]
3. Select `Unix Spool (Movemail)`.

   [image]

The UI to access this menu is slightly different in Thunderbird 2, but I didn't have it handy.

In Thunderbird 2, do the following, adapted from the [Gmail FAQ](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=86399):

1. Click the Tools menu, and select Account Settings..
2. Click the Add Account... button to launch Account Wizard.
3. Select Movemail from the list.

Comment: Well, now I feel foolish. (I'd tried some time ago and hope that the option in the wizard post-dates that, else I don't know how I missed it!) Thanks.  It was also necessary to run `sudo chmod 01777 /var/mail` to get this to work, as without, thunderbird complained it couldn't write a `~.lock` file.

Comment: @vanden: You should find a lower permission that works or create a group that allows access. World writeable is dangerous.

Comment: @Dennis: Thanks. I wasn't pleased by the permissions, either. They were suggested by the thunderbird interface. I tried removing world write access, but that prevented access to the mail. Having fetched the backlog, I've reverted.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible anymore currently, but should be when https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1802145 is achieved.