# Ubuntu 21.10 - Thunderbird 91.x.x drops (movemail) mbox support!

Tags: thunderbird, 21.10, mbox

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 21.04 to Ubuntu 21.10.

Baring a few glitches here and there, it's now running ok.

However, I just discovered that Thunderbird 91.x.x removed movemail support! That means that I've lost support for my /var/mail/* mboxes!

Other than installing another mail program, like possibly `Evolution`, is there any way to get to my mboxes again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

source: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1625741

excerpt from comment 35...

> Anyway, for whoever wants to know a slightly kludgy but likely "good enough" workaround, do this:
>
> - context-click on the "Local Folders" and find the "Local Directory" address
> - close thunderbird (maybe be paranoid and pgrep to ensure you don't have any persistent subprocess still running)
> - then create a symlink ln -s /var/mail/[SPOOL_FILE_NAME] /path/to/the/Local-Directory/address/you/found/above/Inbox (obviously ensure there isn't already an Inbox subfolder there, or otherwise create a differently named subfolder-symlink)
>
> When I opened thunderbird it indexed it OK and after exiting and reopening thunderbird several times the symlink has stayed in place without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it with just one additional `apt install` (less hacky, but requires an imap-server - which is easy to setup, nothing to configure just install):

- https://askubuntu.com/a/1395815/40498
- [How do I read local email in thunderbird?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192572/how-do-i-read-local-email-in-thunderbird#comment2403634_192615)